# What does the value "desktop" mean for the credStore attribute in docker config?

Tags: docker, credentials

In the `.docker/config.json` there is the `credStore` attribute, which apparently the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) is meant to point to an external credential store like the native keychain of an OS, to look out for the credentials of a registry to push and pull images to and from.

But I could not find the meaning after researching the value `desktop` for that attribute. I am unsure whether I added it automatically by some configurations I did earlier.

```
"credsStore": "desktop"
```

Comment: This can give you some idea.
https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/149

Answer (score 8):

I am using docker-desktop for windows, after reading [this answer from the Docker Windows Desktop forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-windows-desktop-credentials-location/107251/2), i found out *desktop* in my case correspondes to the *Credential Manager for Windows*.
I also get the same results for:

```
docker-credential-desktop.exe list
docker-credential-wincred.exe list
```

These docker-desktop commands can be found under *Docker\resources\bin* in the Docker installation directory.

I also checked the [Credential Manager from Control Panel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0) settings under windows and i found my docker credentials.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

My experience on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 :

Looks like the value desktop means to look for credentials on some Docker Desktop configuration, because I installed Docker desktop on Ubuntu, then I uninstalled it manually, but it left this key pair credsStore:desktop value in $HOME/.docker/config.json file.
A few days later I installed docker engine without docker desktop, and when I tried to build a container image I got an error about credentials not found in some desktop file not found.

ERROR: failed to solve: node: error getting credentials - err: docker-credential-desktop resolves to executable in current directory (./docker-credential-desktop), out: ``

So I remembered about uninstalling Docker Desktop a few days before, and checked config.json and found that "desktop" value for credsStore key . I deleted the key/value pair on that file, saved it, and tried to build my container image again, it worked smoothly :)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Now I do not have credsStore in ~/.docker/config.json. but what if I wanted other credStore. what other alternatives I have if I want to store it.